# What are the names of the 2 types of beacon a phone and an AP send

Tags: router, access-point

As I understand it your phone (Android) sends out beacons to ask local access points if they are one of its preferred networks.
Access points also send out beacons announcing they are there.
What are the specific names given to these two types of beacons?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [source](http://edwardkeeble.com/2014/02/passive-wifi-tracking/), the signals your phone sends out are called Probe Requests and the signals the Router/AP sends out are called Beacon Frames.

Answer (score 0):

An end-station would send beacons for an Ad-Hoc network, but not to a WAP. You should really get the scoop directly from the [IEEE 802.11 Wireless LAN Standards](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html), but Wikipedia has a description of the [management frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Management_frames) which IEEE 802.11 uses:

> Management frames allow for the maintenance of communication. Some
>   common 802.11 subtypes include:
>
> - Authentication frame: 802.11 authentication begins with the Wireless    network interface card (WNIC) sending an authentication
>     frame to the    access point containing its identity. With an open
>     system    authentication, the WNIC sends only a single authentication
>     frame,    and the access point responds with an authentication frame
>     of its own    indicating acceptance or rejection. With shared key
>     authentication,    after the WNIC sends its initial authentication
>     request it will    receive an authentication frame from the access
>     point containing    challenge text. The WNIC sends an authentication
>     frame containing the    encrypted version of the challenge text to the
>     access point. The    access point ensures the text was encrypted with
>     the correct key by    decrypting it with its own key. The result of
>     this process determines    the WNIC's authentication status.
> - Association request frame: Sent from a station it enables the access    point to allocate resources and synchronize. The frame
>     carries    information about the WNIC, including supported data rates
>     and the    SSID of the network the station wishes to associate with.
>     If the    request is accepted, the access point reserves memory and
>     establishes    an association ID for the WNIC.
> - Association response frame: Sent from an access point to a station    containing the acceptance or rejection to an association request. If
>     it is an acceptance, the frame will contain information such an
>     association ID and supported data rates.
> - Beacon frame: Sent periodically from an access point to announce its    presence and provide the SSID, and other parameters for WNICs
>     within    range.
> - Deauthentication frame: Sent from a station wishing to terminate    connection from another station.
> - Disassociation frame: Sent from a station wishing to terminate    connection. It's an elegant way to allow the access point to
>     relinquish memory allocation and remove the WNIC from the association 
>     table.
> - Probe request frame: Sent from a station when it requires information    from another station.
> - Probe response frame: Sent from an access point containing capability    information, supported data rates, etc., after receiving
>     a probe    request frame.
> - Reassociation request frame: A WNIC sends a reassociation request    when it drops from range of the currently associated access point and 
>     finds another access point with a stronger signal. The new access
>     point coordinates the forwarding of any information that may still be 
>     contained in the buffer of the previous access point.
> - Reassociation response frame: Sent from an access point containing    the acceptance or rejection to a WNIC reassociation request frame.
>     The frame includes information required for association such as the
>     association ID and supported data rates.

Comment: TL;DR Access Points send *beacons* (per standard, 10 per second). Clients send *probes*.